# I unable to set Custom Label for X Axis by using with SwiftChart Library

Tags: ios, swift

I integrated SwiftChart library through Cocoapods, and successfully I can able to use swiftChart properties for the line chart. But I want to customize the X-Axis labels as I have some dates(2018/06/12, 2018/06/13, etc..) to display on X-Axis. Could you please guide me on this. 
I have integrated the library for my requirement
https://github.com/gpbl/SwiftChart.

Answer (score 2):

You only should read the documentation, I found this code and it may be what you need:

```
// Use `xLabels` to add more labels, even if empty
chart.xLabels = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24]
// Format the labels with a unit
chart.xLabelsFormatter = { String(Int(round($1))) + "h" }
```

The before code, it's for adding 'h', on each value, you can make a function to solve it with your requirements.

**EDIT**

You can make a parallel array, with your required dates i.e ["2018/06/12", "2018/06/13", "2018/06/13","2018/06/13","2018/06/13"] and the array for xLabels i.e [3, 5, 12, 5, 34].. both with the same number of items, and you can replace value for the one this array of dates on the same index..

**You have the index on the sugar syntax $0** within the chart.xLabelsFormatter = { }

```
open var xLabelsFormatter = { (labelIndex: Int, labelValue: Double) -> String in
    String(Int(labelValue))
}
```

Comment: I already saw this code in the documentation but it is not reaching my requirements to customize.

Comment: Thanks, @Lito Problem Solved.

Comment: I'm glad, you can put the answer how success with the green checker?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved my problem by creating the separate array which contains the same count of actual array objects and used that array to display on x-axis label.

```
let mainArray = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12,] 
let displayArray = ["01/03/18", "012/03/18", "15/03/18", "17/03/18", "20/03/18"]
self.chartView.xLabels = mainArray
self.chartView.xLabelsFormatter =  { (labelIndex: Int, labelValue: Double) -> String in
            return displayArray[labelIndex]
        } self.chartView.add(series)
```